# distribution from retirement plan in one state being taxed in another

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, retirement-plan

In 2012, I took a "non-qualified" premature distribution from a retirement plan. I realize that this is taxable on the federal level, and I have paid the federal taxes on it.

I received the funds from the distribution in March 2012 - at this time I was a resident of South Dakota (no state income tax.) All of those funds were earned while I was working living and working in SD.

I moved to and established residence in the state of California at the beginning of May 2012. This qualifies me as a part-year California resident. I did file the part-year resident version of the California tax return for 2012.

Today, I received a Proposed Assessment from the CA Franchise Tax Board claiming that I owe taxes on the premature distribution. **Considering that the funds were paid to me while I was a resident of SD, doesn't that mean that I don't owe any CA taxes on that money?** I do have copies of documentation showing my lease in CA starting in May of 2012 and can provide this in my protest.

Comment: But can you provide proof that you were still a resident of South Dakota in March of 2012?

Comment: I do have proof of it through my employer.

Comment: But can you prove that you still lived in South Dakota in March? Giving them a document that doesn't cover the date in question doesn't prove anything.

Comment: The paystubs I have from my employer show that I was living and working in South Dakota on the date that the distribution was made.

Comment: Than that's what you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

California is very aggressive when it comes to determining residency. While you have a legitimate defense, I suggest talking with a California-licensed CPA or EA practicing in California, which are experienced in dealing with the FTB residency audits.